# ¿Cómo obtener los días festivos desde una base de datos? PHP/MySQLi

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Este código sirve para imprimir los días hábiles y evitar los días festivos. Lo que deseo es evitar que los días festivos no sean capturados y que se saquen desde una base de datos:

```
$holidayDays=[
    '2018-12-24',
        '2018-12-25',
    '2018-12-26',
        '2018-12-27',
    '2018-12-28',
    '2018-12-29'
];
```

El código original es el siguiente:

```
function number_of_working_datesX($from, $days){
    $workingDays = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; # date format = N (1 = Monday, ...)
    $holidayDays=[

        '2018-12-21',
        '2018-12-22',
        '2018-12-23',
        '2018-12-24',
        '2018-12-25',
        '2018-12-26',
        '2018-12-27',
        '2018-12-28',
        '2018-12-29',
        '2018-12-30'
    ];
    $from = new DateTime($from);
    $datesX = [];
    $datesX[] = $from->format('Y-m-d');
    while ($days) {
        $from->modify('+1 day');
        if (!in_array($from->format('N'), $workingDays)) continue;
        if (in_array($from->format('Y-m-d'), $holidayDays)) continue;
        if (in_array($from->format('*-m-d'), $holidayDays)) continue;
        $datesX[] = $from->format('Y-m-d');
        $days--;
    }
    return $datesX;
}
//print_r( number_of_working_dates('2015-12-23', 10) );
$datesX = number_of_working_datesX("$date", $diasantesdemaquila);
foreach ( $datesX as $dateqqqX ) {
    $fechaqqqX=date_create($dateqqqX);
```

Comment: Deep tu pregunta no se entiende. Hablas de mysqli, pero no pones ningún código sobre esa API ni nada que tenga que ver con la base de datos.

Comment: Lo que intente fue hacer esto :$holidayDays=$variabledefechas=['fechas'];

esto lo coloque dentro de una consulta

Comment: Deep lo siento, pero tus comentarios no aclaran nada. Puedes [editar la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/232466/edit) explicando con más exactitud qué es lo que quieres, porque no se entiende. ¿De dónde viene ese array y qué es lo que quieres hacer con él exactamente? Redacta una pregunta clara, nosotros no estamos delante de tu pantalla ni en tu mente para poder saber en qué consiste tu código ni lo que necesitas